# Why is this awk program not giving me any output

Tags: awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was planning on solving the [first](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/1) question of aoc2022, using awk, inspired by [someone](https://github.com/mattmight/advent-of-code-2022)'s idea from GitHub. I need to find the sum of elements between the blank spaces.

Here's the awk program,

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { 
current_count = 0 ; 
}
 
NF == 0 {   
print current_count ;   
current_count = 0 ;   
next ; 
}

{ current_count += $0 }
```

But when I run this, I'm not getting any outputs.

```
 awk -f calorie-count.awk < input.txt
```

Any help is appreciated.

The input almost looks like this, with white spaces in between.

```
7569
1357
10134
4696
4423
8869
3562
6597

4038
9038
1352
8005
4811
6281
3961
4023

7234
3510
7728
1569
4583
7495
3941
6015
6531
2637

18211
19347
16113
7314

3359
7199
4527
5384
1752
2422
6301
1923
5957
3000
6835
1986
```

Comment: what @ilkkachu said but at the end you need `END { print current_count }` instead.

Comment: Why is the example "almost"? How does it differ; just more lines, or a different format?

Comment: you might also have a Windows like end-of-line (CR-LF, Carriage Return-Line Feed) input. First do `dos2unix input.txt` on then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but `END { print current_count }` gets the total sum, which is not what I'm looking for. 

I was hoping to find the sum of elements between the blank spaces.
Sorry if the question was a bit vague.

Comment: Thanks @αғsнιη it worked. I was on WSL and never knew this would've been the issue. Thanks man!!

Comment: @tripleee same format with more lines.

Comment: you are welcome! That's a common issue when working on Windows like/generated input on *nix boxes. you will definitely need to add `END { print current_count }` after your first fix (changing CRLF to LF which `dos2unix` commnad does)

Comment: @αғsнιη thanks again

Comment: See [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more info.

Comment: If you know that the file uses CRLF line-endings, an alternative to `dos2unix` is to set awk's input and output record separators (RS and ORS) - i.e. add `RS=ORS="\r\n";` to the `BEGIN` block, or (on the command line) use `awk -v RS="\r\n" -v ORS="\r\n" '...script...'`.   Another option would be to process the input in paragraphs, split each paragraph into an array on \r\n and then sum the array & print it - but that's probably more effort than it's worth.